# Interested in vs interested

Tags: word-usage

When must we use the preposition **in** when we used the word interested.

Normal Usage:

> I am interested in 18th century paintings.

How about these examples:

> If you're interested don't hesitate to send me message.

or

a dialogue I saw in the Simpsons

> Ned Flanders: Well looks like someone's having a pre-rapture party.
>
> Homer Simpson: No, Flanders. It's a meeting of gay witches for
>   abortion, you wouldn't be interested.

If I added **in** in the examples, what would they imply ?

> If you're interested in don't hesitate to send me message.
>
> Its a meeting of gay witches for abortion, you wouldn't be interested
>   in.

Comment: The key here is context. In general you don't repeat what has already been established as context, so if you've already said or written "I am interested in 18th century paintings" that sets the context for a later "If you're interested, don't hesitate ..." in which "in 18th century paintings" is implied, not explicitly stated. Also, it's "If you're interested" not "if you interested".

Comment: In your last example, it's either "be interested" [in something implied by the established context],  or explicitly "interested in something". You can't use "interested in." (period). In general there's something wrong if a sentence ends in a preposition, although in colloquial speech there are exceptions.

Comment: You have already gotten good answers, but I recommend taking @nigel222's statement that something is wrong with ending a sentence with a preposition except in colloquial speech. That was a rule a century or more ago, but not any more. Winston Churchill, a most correct speaker of English, when someone corrected him for using a preposition to end a sentence, is credited with replying, "This is the sort of bloody nonsense up with which I will not put!" Just avoid ending with a preposition that is not necessary: Never say, "Where is Henry at?" Mrs. Creighton, my 10th grade English teacher would te

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it simply, *to be interested in* is usually followed by an object, whereas *to be interested* isn't.

> I am interested in 18th century paintings.

In the above quote, *to be interested in* is used because it is directly followed by the object (18th century paintings).

However, in the below quote, no object is followed, which is why *to be interested in* is not used, but rather, simply *to be interested*. If you wanted to use *to be interested in*, you can simply add the object at the end of the statement, as can be seen in my addition (in bold text):

> Homer Simpson: No, Flanders. It's a meeting of gay witches for
> abortion, you wouldn't be interested *in **it**.*

Similarly, in your other examples, simply add the object in order to make the sentences proper and complete. You can do so as follows (my additions can be seen in bold):

> If you're interested in **it** don't hesitate to send me message.
>
> Its a meeting of gay witches for abortion, you wouldn't be interested
> in **it**

However, the sentences would be perfectly fine without the use of *to be interested in* in this case. Usually, the less verbose form is seen and heard.

Answer (score 4):

You add 'in' if you want to specify the object of interest. You leave it out if it's implied from context.

If you just say "I am interested", without context, it's impossible to tell what you're interested in. That's why you'd specify: "I am interested *in 18th century paintings*." or "I am interested *in the outcome of the election*.", etc.

However, if you're already talking about something, it will be implied as the object of your interest, and it would be redundant to specify. So, in your second example, Ned and Homer both know they're talking about a gathering of people, so Homer doesn't have to say "You wouldn't be interested *in the meeting*."

Simply adding 'in' without providing an object (as you do in your examples) is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The **in** is just pointing to the object that you are interested with

> I am interested *in*, **object**.

I'm not interested **object**,
but I am interested **in** an **object**.
for example

> I am interested *in* 18th century paintings.
>
> I am interested *in* sports.

So if you are talking about your interest you always use **in** and the object.

Now in your other context that is also correct because it's a response so you wouldn't have to specify what the subject (**object**) is.
If I am making a statement then you wouldn't know the subject until I have made my statement. In a response to that statement I would already know the subject so you wouldn't have to specify. Therefore if you don't need to specify the subject you also would not need the pointer (**in**) to point to the subject.
for example,

> "I am interested in 18th century paintings".

"**If you are interested,** don't hesitate to send me a message.

> "I am interested in sports".

"**If you are interested**, you should watch ESPN".

Answer (score 1):

**I am interested** or

**I am interested in it**

"I am interested in" has no object.